# Make PostgreSQL recover two geometry coordinates points split into columns

Tags: postgresql, coordinates, query

So I want to make a SQL that converts my PostgreSQL coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2) to 4 different columns. By now this is what I have:

```sql
trim ('MULTILINESTRING((' from (split_part(ST_AsText(SSDMT.geom), ' ', 1))) as xi, 
split_part(split_part(ST_AsText(SSDMT.geom), ' ', 2), ',', 1) as yi,
split_part(split_part(ST_AsText(SSDMT.geom), ' ', 2), ',', 2) as xf,
trim ('))' from (split_part(ST_AsText(SSDMT.geom), ' ', 3))) as yf
```

And it returns:
[image]

I also made this one:

```sql
trim('[[[' from (split_part((ST_AsGeoJSON(SSDMT.geom)::JSON->>'coordinates')::text, ',', 1))) as xi,
trim(']' from (split_part((ST_AsGeoJSON(SSDMT.geom)::JSON->>'coordinates')::text, ',', 2))) as yi,
trim('[' from (split_part((ST_AsGeoJSON(SSDMT.geom)::JSON->>'coordinates')::text, ',', 3))) as xf,
trim(']]]' from (split_part((ST_AsGeoJSON(SSDMT.geom)::JSON->>'coordinates')::text, ',', 4))) as yf
```

And it returns:
[image]

Is there a better way to do this?

The original query:

```sql
SELECT
SSDMT."COD_ID" ID_CABO, 
SU."COD_ID" ID_SUB, SU."NOM" NOM_SUB, 
CT."COD_ID" ID_ALIM, CT."NOM" NOM_ALIM, 
SSDMT."FAS_CON" FASES,
SSDMT."COMP" COMPRIMENTO,
CBIT."COD_ID" COD_BITOLA,
CBIT."DESCR" NOME_BITOLA,
CMAT."COD_ID" COD_MATERIAL,
CMAT."DESCR" NOM_MATERIAL,
SC."R1",
SC."X1",
ST_AsGeoJSON(SSDMT.geom)::json->'coordinates' as COORD
from "BDGD2018"."SSDMT" SSDMT
join "BDGD2018"."SEGCON" SC on SSDMT."TIP_CND" = SC."COD_ID"
join "ANEEL"."TCABOBIT" CBIT on SC."BIT_FAS_1" = CBIT."COD_ID"
join "ANEEL"."TCABOMAT" CMAT on SC."MAT_FAS_1" = CMAT."COD_ID"
join "BDGD2018"."CTMT" CT on SSDMT."CTMT" = CT."COD_ID"
join "BDGD2018"."SUB" SU on SSDMT."SUB" = SU."COD_ID"
where SSDMT."CTMT" = 'NLAE733'
```

Returns:
[image]

Comment: Use the proper [geometry accessor functions](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Accessors). What geometry type are you using?

Comment: I'm using this: geom geometry(MultiLineString,4674)
In the past few days I came with this solution:

ST_X(ST_AsText(ST_GeometryN(ST_Points(SSDMT.geom),1);
ST_Y(ST_AsText(ST_GeometryN(ST_Points(SSDMT.geom),1);

Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

Use [ST_GeometryN](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryN.html) to get the linestring out of the multilinestring, [ST_PointN](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointN.html) do get the first/second point, and [ST_X](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html)/[ST_Y](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html) to get the points' coordinates:

```
SELECT ST_X(ST_PointN(ST_GeometryN(tab.geom, 1), 1)) AS xi,
       ST_Y(ST_PointN(ST_GeometryN(tab.geom, 1), 1)) AS yi,
       ST_X(ST_PointN(ST_GeometryN(tab.geom, 1), 2)) AS xf,
       ST_Y(ST_PointN(ST_GeometryN(tab.geom, 1), 2)) AS yf
...
```

Comment: Thx! 
Is the solution below bad?

`ST_X(ST_AsText(ST_GeometryN(ST_Points(SSDMT.geom),1)`
`ST_Y(ST_AsText(ST_GeometryN(ST_Points(SSDMT.geom),1)`

Comment: That is not valid SQL (parentheses do not match), and that combination of functions does not make sense.